# How to consolidate several excel files with several sheets in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, xlsx

I want to consolidate 7 excel files with several sheets in R. All sheets have the same structure. I try to use a for but the result is the last workbook or error. The code is:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")
sheets <- excel_sheets(files)
library(xlsx)
setwd("C:/Users/User/Documents")

for(i in 1:7){
  file <- files
  vari <- sheets %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map_df(~ read_excel(path,skip = 5 ,sheet = .x), .id = "sheet")
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Your for loop makes no sense. The point of using `purrr::map()` here.is to avoid a for loop. Just try with the last bit of code that creates the object `vari`.

Answer (score 0):

I will offer such a solution.
You can compose a `data.frame` with a list of files and sheets in them. Then use `map2_dfr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
setwd("C:/tmp") 

path <- list.files(".", pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = T)

df_files <- data.frame(files = path) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sheets = list(excel_sheets(files))) %>% 
  unnest(sheets)

df <- map2_dfr(.x = df_files$files, .y = df_files$sheets, readxl::read_xlsx)
```

Comment: does not work, this appears: Error: `path` must be a string

Comment: Please check with a reproducible example. Link to example data `https://yadi.sk/d/WXyr6KM0z5WVVQ`
Everything works for me without errors.